# How to scrape data from whatsapp web

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen, whatsapp

I want to scrape text, names, iamges, and other items from my WhatsApp web for testing.

I am thinking to scrape using scrapy and splash because WhatsApp web is Java script dependent, using xpath expression and maybe css selectors.

**I need guidance on proper way to scrape WhatsApp**, and any information about its code will help.

Or maybe any relative source code you could provide.

Also, if I scan the QR code of the website via my WhatsApp mobile app, how can I maintain the same session because when I visit web.whatsapp.com using the splash browser or selenium? It obviously is a different browser and how can I scan the QR code there somehow and save the session of my WhatsApp web, or somehow transfer my session to my splash browser?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775630/is-it-possible-to-scrape-all-text-messages-from-whatsapp-web-with-scrapy